# August 2019 - Could anyone identify this rose for me please

Tags: identification

[image]

This rose is from my late mother’s garden. Can anyone identify please? Many thanks, Katy

Answer (score 1):

Identifying roses from a single flower is very hard. Sometimes you can get close to it by first identifying what class of roses the example belongs to, that is: hybrid tea, multiflora, climber and so on and then looking at rose catalogues to find an example which is the same colour, but your question does not contain enough information to help in this process. Rose breeders are constantly looking for magic new colours combined with other characteristics, so the books are filled with what looks like your rose but might not be. Adding to the confusion is the possibility that the breeder re-names a known variety because it makes the product more marketable.

Ideally your mother will have left records showing what was bought in for the garden. It would be somewhat unusual for a rose to be older than about 20 years.

If your motivation is to preserve a part of your mother's garden for sentimental reasons then there is really no substitute for taking a piece of the genuine article and growing it on either as a grafted scion or on its own roots. As Shakespeare once noted, "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet."

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is floribunda by the breeder Christian Bédard.  It was introduced in 2012 by Weeks Rose, they call it Ketchup and Mustard.  The flower is much better than the name.   If the rose has been in her garden well before 2012, then I am wrong.